# Find $\sum_{k=1}^nk\lfloor k\varphi\rfloor$, where $\varphi$ is golden ratio

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions, golden-ratio

I've got this far, which is nothing really. Assuming $S(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\lfloor k\varphi\rfloor$, for which we have a recursive formula (see here: [Solve summation $\sum_{i=1}^n \lfloor e\cdot i \rfloor $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2307399/solve-summation-sum-i-1n-lfloor-e-cdot-i-rfloor)), we can write out sum as
$$
1\lfloor\varphi\rfloor+2\lfloor2\varphi\rfloor+\ldots+n\lfloor n\varphi\rfloor=
$$
$$
=S(n)+(S(n)-S(1))+(S(n)-S(2))+\ldots+(S(n)-S(n-1))=
$$
$$
=nS(n)-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}S(k).
$$
Computationally, this is obviously very slow. Anything faster? Thanks.

Comment: It may be of interest to note that $S(n)$ as presented is sequence [A054347](http://oeis.org/A054347) and has a reference therein that may lead to further information.